# Flutter CustomPainter canvas rotate pivot

Tags: canvas, flutter, android-canvas, flutter-layout

In my Android Studio project, I rotate the canvas simply as following

`canvas.rotate(angle, cx, cy);`

with cx and cy the center of the screen (i.e. the pivot). But in Flutter, there's only a single rotate method:

`canvas.rotate(double radians)`

and as you can see, when I tested the pivot it uses by drawing some rectangles and rotating it

[image]

and it uses top-left as pivot point. Is there a way to instruct Flutter to use my own provided pivot point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
canvas.translate(cx, cy);
canvas.rotate(angle);
canvas.translate(-cx, -cy);
```

<strike>it's possible I have lines 1 and 3 reversed.</strike> Fixed.

Comment: and yes lines 1 and 3 are reversed