# How to Draw multiple Rectangle with different rotation in Flutter Canvas?

Tags: flutter, flutter-canvas

I am trying to add multiple Rectangles in the Canvas and rotate them with user pan action. But the Constructor I found till now for Rect is all to draw them without Rotation. and I found a method `canvas.rotate()` which will rotate the whole canvas.

How to achieve this? Any code where rotation of the Rectangle is dealt with user pan action without using `canvas.rotate()` will be helpful.

Comment: you either need `canvas.rotate()` or `canvas.transform()` - without them you will not draw rotated rectangle - you can use `canvas.rotate()` like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64758628/rotate-painted-text-about-its-center/64772650#64772650

Comment: So, if I rotate the whole canvas, how can I rotate one Rectangle 20 degree and another 40 degree

Comment: see the link i posted

Comment: Sorry for being naive, I get that this code is Transforming and rotating Then Transforming kind of like suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58042432/flutter-custompainter-canvas-rotate-pivot/58042557#58042557 
but while I Rotate the second Rect won't the 1st one will also be rotated as we are rotating the whole canvas.

Comment: post your code then: with canvas save>translate>rotate>translate>drawRect>restore

Comment: I understood the answer now. every rotation enclosed by `canvas.save()` and `canvas.restore()` will not effect other element.
Thanks, @pskink . The code is working now.

Comment: but if you want to make it shorter you can also just use `Canvas.transform()`, so you call: transform > drawRect transform > drawRect etc, the problem is that `Matrix4` api is not easy... here you have some helper method: `Matrix4 rotate(double angle, Offset focalPoint) {
var c = cos(angle);
var s = sin(angle);
var dx = (1 - c) * focalPoint.dx + s * focalPoint.dy;
var dy = (1 - c) * focalPoint.dy - s * focalPoint.dx;
return Matrix4(c, s, 0, 0, -s, c, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, dx, dy, 0, 1);
}`

Comment: Can you please add some example code. and Some link on how to understand `Canvas.transform()` 
also if you could add your answer in the Answer below, I could select it as Right answer.

Comment: i was wrong: `save()` and `restore()` are still needed: `final r0 = Rect.fromLTWH(100, 100, 300, 100);
final r1 = Rect.fromLTWH(100, 300, 300, 100);

canvas.save();
canvas.transform(rotate(pi/6, r0.center).storage);
canvas.drawRect(r0, paint);
canvas.restore();
canvas.save();
canvas.transform(rotate(-pi/6, r1.center).storage);
canvas.drawRect(r1, paint);
canvas.restore();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is simple as @pskink answered in the comment above.

There is only `canvas.rotate()` and `canvas.transform()` to rotate anything in the flutter canvas and there is `canvas.scale()` to scale them.

now if you want to rotate one object 120, and another 40 degrees you need to draw them inside a `canvas.save()` ... `canvas.restore()` block. then your objects will be rotated at a different angles. look at the below code for example:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

const kCanvasSize = 300.0;

class ImageInsideRectPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ImageInsideRectPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ImageInsideRectPageState createState() => _ImageInsideRectPageState();
}

class _ImageInsideRectPageState extends State<ImageInsideRectPage> {
  ui.Image? image;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _load('assets/img.png');
    super.initState();
  }

  void _load(String path) async {
    var bytes = await rootBundle.load(path);
    image = await decodeImageFromList(bytes.buffer.asUint8List());
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.greenAccent, width: 2)),
          height: kCanvasSize,
          width: kCanvasSize,
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: ImageInsideRectangle(context: context, image: image),
            child: SizedBox.expand(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ImageInsideRectangle extends CustomPainter {
  ImageInsideRectangle({required this.context, required this.image});
  ui.Image? image;
  final BuildContext context;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) async {
    canvas.clipRRect(ui.RRect.fromRectXY(
      Rect.fromPoints(Offset(0, 0), Offset(kCanvasSize - 4, kCanvasSize - 4)),
      0,
      0,
    ));
    Paint greenBrush = Paint()..color = Colors.greenAccent;
    if (image != null) {
      canvas.save();
      rotate(
          canvas: canvas,
          cx: image!.width.toDouble() / 2,
          cy: image!.height.toDouble() / 2,
          angle: -0.3);
      canvas.scale(kCanvasSize / image!.height);
      canvas.drawImage(image!, Offset(0, 0), greenBrush);
      canvas.restore();
    }
    canvas.save();
    rotate(canvas: canvas, cx: 200 + 50, cy: 100 + 50, angle: 0.5);
    canvas.drawRect(Rect.fromLTWH(200, 100, 100, 100), greenBrush);
    canvas.restore();
  }

  void rotate(
      {required Canvas canvas,
      required double cx,
      required double cy,
      required double angle}) {
    canvas.translate(cx, cy);
    canvas.rotate(angle);
    canvas.translate(-cx, -cy);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}

Future<ui.Image> loadUiImage(String imageAssetPath) async {
  final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(imageAssetPath);
  final Completer<ui.Image> completer = Completer();
  ui.decodeImageFromList(Uint8List.view(data.buffer), (ui.Image img) {
    return completer.complete(img);
  });
  return completer.future;
}
```

This way you can rotate multiple objects in multiple directions. also, there is an example of loading an image from local asset and rotating it around its own center.

Comment: Thank you soo much Zihan :3  you helped me a lot!