# Flutter: How to rotate an Image before execute paintImage()

Tags: flutter, canvas

I have a `CustomPainter`. In its `paint()` method I am drawing an image:

```
var _myImage = _loadImage();

// do some rotation stuff here...

paintImage(
  canvas: _myCanvas,
  fit: BoxFit.contain,
  image: _myImage
);
```

That works fine. However, I want to rotate the image by 30° before I actually put this onto the canvas.

I already saw this: [Flutter - How to rotate an image around the center with canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51323233/flutter-how-to-rotate-an-image-around-the-center-with-canvas)

But I don't want to rotate the canvas, I want to rotate the image before drawing. The reason is: I will paint several images in different angles.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can anly rotate the canvas: either by `Canvas.rotate` or `Canvas.transform` and you can always surround those methods with `Canvas.save` and `Canvas.restore` - by doing that you can easily call `Canvas.rotate` or `Canvas.transform` multiple times

Comment: @pskink to be more precise: I need one image with rotated by 30 degrees, and one with 60 degrees. Is this possible with your way? Could you provide an example?

Comment: `canvas..save()..transform(matrix1)..drawImage(img1, offset1, paint)..restore(); canvas..save()..transform(matrix2)..drawImage(img2, offset2, paint)..restore();`

Comment: @pskink And then there are two rotated images on an unrotated canvas?

Comment: yes indeed, two rotated images, for `Matrix4` manipulations check those [three](https://github.com/pskink/matrix_gesture_detector/blob/master/lib/matrix_gesture_detector.dart#L174-L216) "magic" methods

Comment: I will test. Please feel free to put this as answer. Then I can accept if it works